# Deploying microservices to Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry

I developed a simple prototype of a complete microservice architecture with Spring Cloud and OSS libraries that I can run fluently on my computer. I'm trying to deploy the whole thing to Cloud Foundry, and going throught the documentation I found a lot of articles discussing how to use PCF discovery service, but how about using our eureka server? I tried to use `user provided service` but my microservices can't bind to the URL even when restaging them. How can I achieve such thing?

The second question is (If I can make eureka works): should I declare my config server also as a user provided service?

Comment: Did you see this article? It's a little bit Pivotal specific, but you should be able to do the same thing with all OSS software with a little extra work: https://content.pivotal.io/blog/building-spring-microservices-with-cloud-foundrys-new-container-networking-stack

Answer (score 1):

Following the docs [create-user-provided-service](https://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/create-user-provided-service.html)

You should first create the cups like this:

> 1. cf cups SERVICE_INSTANCE -p PATH_TO_FILE

the file could be a json file with a content like this:    {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}

> 2. bind your app to the service through a manifest.yml file that resides in your app directory

```
services: 
 -SERVICENAME
```

> 3. get the service value through an application.yml file property like this
>
>    url: ${vcap.services.servicename.key1}
>
>    for default values you can do
>
>    url: ${vcap.services.servicename.key1:defaultURL}

After you have created the cups, the manifest.yml and the aplication.yml, you have to push your application or restart it.

Should I declare my config server also as a user provided service?

> I believe you should, your config server will probably be accesed by
>   multiple microservices therefore you should keep the config server url
>   in the user provided service and connect your multiple apps to this service.